# How to generate unique number of 10 digits based on combination of 4 columns in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a scenario, where I want to generate unique numbers based on combination of 4 columns.

Example:

```
A B C D -- 100200300
A B C E -- 100200301
A B C D -- 100200300
A B C F -- 100200302
```

Whenever the combination is matching it should always generate the number it generated before in case that combination has been found earlier. Possible a oracle function would be great.

Comment: What is in the four columns?  Just a single letter?

Comment: Take Gordon't question seriously. If "a single letter" then there are only 26 possible values in each column, so what you want is possible. If there are 1000 values possible in each column, then the total number of combinations is much more than 10^10, so what you want is impossible.

Comment: these four columns are defined as following..
column A - employer -  number number type
column B - employee - varchar2 (9 digits, Sometime 100200400, sometimes 10030040P)
Column C - Year (Ex 2000, 2012)
Column D - Month (Ex, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

Comment: i have got **70 mil** records to deal with.

Comment: please edit your question. add this information from the comments. for each column also add the range of its values and the number of distint values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the hashing function ora_hash() and see if that will work for you.
e.g.

```
ora_hash(c1||'-'||c2||'-'||...)
```

You can also explore the hash functions in dbms_crypto package

Comment: I don't think `ORA_HASH` would be appropriate here since that function is designed to generate collisions.  But the functions in `DBMS_CRYPTO`, or the 12c function `STANDARD_HASH`, would be much better suited to produce hashes without a realistic chance of a collision.  There's still the issue of how to save the results though - the original poster wanted a numeric representation but most hashes can't fit into an Oracle number without losing precision.

Comment: i checked ora_hash. I have checked it with 1,918,898 records initially but out of that 1,918,468 is distinct. So I can tell you its duplicated. I have to have some solution which will generate unique number incase new combination found. I have total 70 millions records to deal with. for other function standard_hash, i have to generate a 10 digit number. Is it possible to generate that. But we have to consider the fact that in case the combination is matching i should be able to generate the same number which it has already generated.

Comment: i am not able to use standard_has function. can you please show me an example.

Comment: my database is Oracle 11.2.0.4

Comment: can you please give an example for DBMS_CRYPTO also?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing this on one character values, you can use the `ASCII` function to pull the number like so:

```
SELECT '00' || ASCII('A') || ASCII('B') || ASCII('C') || ASCII('D')
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '00' || ASCII('W') || ASCII('X') || ASCII('Y') || ASCII('Z') 
FROM dual
```

Which provides: `0065666768` and `0087888990`

I added the `00` at the start to give the 10 characters as requested, you could add those or whatever other characters you wanted anywhere you like.  This will give you the same result for the same values each time though is problematic with lowercase letters as their codes are longer than 2 digits.

Comment: Not doing it on character type columns. All are number columns.

Comment: Please edit your question with actual sample data then and desired results, your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot realistically be accomplished.  Without using a mapping table or a ridiculously lucky function you cannot generate a number that is unique, deterministic, 10 digits, and represents 70 million items.

Your requirements are running into the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  For example, what are the chances of two people in the same room sharing a birthday?  We naively think the chances are 50% with half of 365, but the real answer is the chances are 50% with only 23 people.

Likewise, the chance of generating 70 million random numbers out of 10 billion, and not having any collisions, is 0% after rounding.

Although it's possible I'm using the approximation functions from that Wikipedia article incorrectly.  Perhaps the approximations do not hold true for large values.

```
select 1 - power(2.71828, (-power(70000000, 2) / (2*9999999999))) from dual;
```

The answer from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/884002 also predicts a collision:

```
select power(70000000, 2) / (2*9999999999) from dual;
```

Unless you're willing to create a mapping table with 70 million values you need to relax one of the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ROWID to generate unique number for each rows.

```
SELECT ROWID FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: will not repeat as requested when the same 4 column pattern is encountered.

Comment: The `ROWID` may also change for a row over time.